# Webkit breaks the layout on iOS when faced with @font-face

Tags: iphone, ios, webkit, svg, font-face

There are two breaks that I couldn't solve. It renders correctly on Firefox, Safari and Chrome, however on iPad and iPhone, somehow the rightmost link at the menu is broken. How can I fix this? The second breaking is at footer, as I have declared the size in em's, it should scale, but it doesn't. I'd be very thankful if anybody has an idea why.

Screenshots are:

First:

[image: first]

Second:

[image: second]

Comment: UIKit seems to use slightly different font sizing/layout than Mac OS (line heights increased slightly in iOS 3, for one). It looks a bit like your width is not quite big enough, causing the text to wrap.

Comment: I see. I expected mobile webkit to respond same as desktop webkit. I'll probably create two stylesheets for each then. Thanks!